# Inaccurate results while retrieving results from image taken from iphone 4 camera

Tags: ios4, ocr, abbyy

I am using ABBYY mobile SDK to retrieve text from image. if i use the image taken by my iphone 4 camera and then i place this image in resource folder of my project, it gives me correct result(refer: [How to get coordinates using abbyy mobile sdk for iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113119/how-to-get-coordinates-using-abbyy-mobile-sdk-for-iphone)) but taking image from camera and directly processing it with SDK APIs do not give me accurate results. For eg. the result is somthing like:

"-55",
    "!l",
    II,
    lie,
    n3,
    "S S--1",
    "I -S s",
    "^ o :=",
    "'*ABBYY*>",
    "^ Q) U",
    "^ -5 -S",
    "i ii",
    "CL

for image [image: image_iphone4.png] (attached).

Which is not correct. I do understand the same image if i use in resource folder of my project will give me correct result . But do not give me correct result if i take this image directly from camera and process it using ABBYY SDK apis.

Please guide.

Comment: In both cases you are using the ABBYY SDK?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you're trying to recognize jpeg image with EXIF information about the image rotation. It is left for user to apply this rotation to the image.

The easiest solution is to use `MIPO_DetectPageOrientation` flag for MobileOCR recognition manager:

```
[fineManager setProcessingOptions:MIPO_DetectPageOrientation];
```

So the MobileOCR engine will try to detect page orientation.

But be aware that recognition with `MIPO_DetectPageOrientation` flag is over 2 times slower than without it.